# Calculating BusLoad on CANoe

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I have been trying to calculate busload in CAPL but it is always 0 no matter how many message signals i send from my node.

I tried using the BusLoad member and some other helps from stack overflow itself but to my vain i couldn't find the solution due to small community. Can someone help me with how to calculate bus load on CAPL.

```
busloadCAN = canGetBusLoad(1);
  write ("CAN1 busload = %d", CAN1.BusLoad);
```

this was soemthing that i tried to use

Comment: Have you checked the busload in the CAN statistics window? What is the value there?

Comment: UPDATE. Previously in CAN statics window The bus load was 0 was well as the the .BusLoad param. Randomly it started working when i made a new configuration.

Comment: Not sure but did you disable "Calculate bus statistics" (File->Options->Measurement performance->Statistics) by any chance?